# How to use style defined in another xaml file inside a style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I had `MultiSelComboBoxStyle` defined in a xaml resource file, and in another xaml resource file, I have

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridDemoStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    ....
    <ComboBox x:Name="ccBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="9" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource MultiSelComboBoxStyle}" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
    ....
</Style>
```

I put every xaml in `App.xaml` and the compiler did find this `MultiSelComboBoxStyle` style , but debugging the program says `MultiSelComboBoxStyle` was not found. In `App.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="DataGridCustomizations.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="MultiSelComboBoxStyle.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Is that ""xaml file" a Resource Dictionary?

Comment: @AbhinavSharma correct

Comment: Have you defined resource dictionary as application resource??

In the above code,please try Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MultiSelComboBoxStyle}"

Comment: @AbhinavSharma yes, I think that's why the compiler finds the `style` for me.(pop up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I need to do

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MultiSelComboBoxStyle.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

If needs to use styles from different resource files.

Comment: I don't understand how does it help to solve the problem ? This line `<ResourceDictionary Source="MultiSelComboBoxStyle.xaml" />` was already included in question